# How to download entire website database

Tags: search, grep, wget

I would like to download the entire database from my local real estate tax search bill. I need to search this data for keywords. I tried using Wget but it seems it only downloaded the links from the site. I am using linux.

Here is the site: http://services.wakegov.com/realestate/

I bascially want all the information that can be searched on that site locally on my computer.

Answer (score 0):

Just call / email them and ask for a copy:

> Tax Bills/Real Estate Data Search
>
> For questions related to data found in tax bill and property searches,
> contact the Wake County Revenue Department at revhelp@wakegov.com or call 919-856-5400